Water farm not working
In Fallout 4 on Xbox One, I started a water farm in Sanctuary, and I have about 600 in my water meter, but I'm not getting any water no matter how long I wait. I only have around 5 settlers there. Do I need more for it to produce anything? As of right now, it isn't making any.

What do you mean by "I'm not getting any water" -- do you mean in storage (workbench)?

After checking the wiki it seems there is a cap of excess production of 5 drinkable items, with that cap raising by 1 for every 4 settlers you have. This cap is not specific to purified water though so if you have dirty water, nuka-cola, alcohol, etc. in your workshop inventory that counts against this cap.
This means you will want to remove all aid items from the workshop inventory and place them in a different storage container, after which the next update should place 6 purified water [the 5 base plus one for the number of settlers you have] in the workbench inventory.
Source: https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout_4_settlements#Water
